# Sapply over list of matrices - knowing index of current element

Tags: r

I am quite new to R and I have found one vector operation frustrating:

I just want to know an index of current element of the list while using sapply, let's say: to print an index, but all my trials do not work, e.g.:

```
> test <- sapply(my.list.of.matrices, 
                 function(x) print(which(my.list.of.matrices == x)))

Error in which(my.list.of.matrices == x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
In addition: Warning message:
  In my.list.of.matrices == x :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I want to refer (in the `function(x)`) to the vector of strings, I mean to vector's element which has THAT (the same as element of list) index.

Comment: it would be nice to be able to do this (i.e. a `.INDEX` special variable of some sort), but I think the canonical way to do this is with `mapply()`

Comment: ...or possibly loop over `seq_along(my.list.of.matrices)` instead.

Comment: @joran, I agree -- your approach is simpler (and hence more robust), but I think mine is marginally more expressive.

Comment: I wanted to be "pro-R" and I tried to use vectors where it is only posssible... Possibly, I do exaggerate. Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible unless you pass an index vector. sapply and lapply just pass the elements. And in that case it becomes a disguised for-loop.